# codeception api testing error 401

Tags: yii2, codeception

i'm new to codeception. wrote a test case to call a sever time api built in Yii2 and see the return code 200. executed it also in debug mode where i can see the response as expected but it always returns 401.

here is my GetServerTime.php

```
<?php
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('check server time');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendGET('http://192.168.1.142/api/server/time',array('service' => "betaserver"));
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

i've also used amDigestAuthentication but didnt work

here is my api.suite.dist.yml file

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://192.168.1.142    
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            url: http://192.168.1.142/api/server/time
            part: Json
        - \Helper\Api
```

note that i'm not using any Yii2 cnfiguration, i simply installed codeception with composer

here is the response i get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPYTT.png)

Comment: Do you have any kind of authorization at your API?

Comment: yes, Http digest based authentication

Comment: but you do not use auth at your test, am i right?

Comment: <?php
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('check server time');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->amDigestAuthenticated('username','pass');
$I->sendGET('https://dev-tv.dna.fi/api/server/time',array('service'=>'password'));
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();

Comment: yes i've used digest auth, here it is 
$I->amDigestAuthenticated('username','pass'); but still 401, and i checked through wireshark the packet its sending is simple http auth